# Browser clipboard copied but disappears immediately?

Tags: browser

The web browser that comes with my phone (Nexus One) allows selecting and copying web page content to clipboard, through the Settings menu ("select text").

The problem is that when I select and copy web page to the clipboard, I receive a confirmation message: "Text copied to clipboard" but... the clipboard is still empty!

How is this possible?

I downloaded from the Android market the free Clipboard Viewer app so that I can see what's in the clipboard and it shows no data in clipboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you've tried actually pasting it, rather than just using the viewer?

Comment: Was it having this problem *before* you installed the free 'Clipboard Viewer' app?

Comment: @Matthew No, I didn't try pasting it. I just tried to view it immediately after selecting & copying to clipboard.

Comment: @Uninspired I can't really answer your question because before installing the clipboard viewer I had no way of knowing whether there is anything in the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try actually pasting it.  You could try the often-built-in Memo app, GMail, Email, or something like Docs to Go if you want to save it.

Comment: Yes, pasting it works. Weird. I thought that a clipboard viewer was supposed to display clipboard content **before** being pasted.

Comment: Yeah I would have expected that too.